# Usar polimorfismo en objetos de clases que implementan la misma interface?

Tags: c#, polimorfismo, interface

¿Es posible? O necesariamente deben heredar de la misma clase padre...

```
public interface interfaz
{

}

public class a : interfaz
{

}

public class b : interfaz
{

}

public class prueba
{
    public void X()
    {
        a objetoA = new b();
    }
}
```

El código tal que así, da un error de compilación ya que las clases a y b son obviamente de diferente tipo.

Ejemplo real;

```
public partial class ConfigNivel : UserControl
{
    public int GetTotal(){};
}

public partial class ConfigCPU : UserControl
{
    public int GetTotal(){};
}
```

Estas, son vistas que cargo en un StackPanel y me gustaría llamar siempre a su método `GetTotal()` una vez las haya instanciado, sean de la clase que sean.

**EDIT NUEVO**

Las vistas que cargue en el `StackPanel` pueden ser 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7... las que sean, todas ellas heredan de la clase UserControl, y todas ellas tienen un metodo que se llama `GetTotal()`, el cual devuelve el calculo de una suma de propiedades de ese objeto.
Lo que quiero hacer es que sean de la clase que sean poder llamar a su método GetTotal() dentro de un `For` o un `Foreach` y obtener así la suma de todos. El problema que tengo ahora es que son objetos de clases distintas : `ConfigNivel`, `ConfigCPU` etc... y no puedo usar poliformfismo. Como ya estan heredadndo de UserControl y C# no admite heredar de varias clases (o eso creo) no se muy bien como hacerlo...
Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Hola Edulon, mientras ambas clases implementen la interfaz en la que se define el método `GetTotal` puedes acceder al método utilizando la interfaz como tipo del objeto. En cualquier caso, si te ha surgido un problema nuevo deberías abrir una nueva pregunta con el código suficiente para reproducir el problema. Si tiene relación con lo explicado en esta pregunta no tienes más que añadir un link a esta pregunta en la nueva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dices, no puedes inicializar una clase de tipo `a` con una instancia de tipo `b`. Lo que debes hacer en estos casos es usar la interface como tipo. Por ejemplo, asi:

```
interfaz objetoA = new a();
interfaz objetoB = new b();
```

Si después necesitas comprobar de que tipo es cada una de las instancias creadas, puedes usar `is` o `typeof`:

```
if (objetoA is A) { ... }
if (objetoA.GetType() == typeof(B)) { ... }
```

Por último, si necesitas asignar esta variable a un tipo concreto, deberás hacer un cast:

```
A objetoC = (A)objetoA;
```

**Edit:**

Usemos tu ejemplo real:

```
public interface interfaz
{
    int GetTotal();
}

public class a : interfaz
{
    public int GetTotal() { return 1; }
}

public class b : interfaz
{
    public int GetTotal() { return 2; }
}
```

Instanciar y llamar al método de interfaz no tiene problema:

```
a varA = new a();
b varB = new b();

varA.GetTotal();
varB.GetTotal();
```

Creamos un método que reciba un objeto de una clase que implementa `interfaz`:

```
public static int metodo(interfaz variable)
{
    return variable.GetTotal();
}
```

Llamar a éste método tampoco:

```
metodo(varA);
metodo(varB);
```

Comment: Hola Pikoh, el problema es que yo tengo dos vistas, que heredan de la clase UserControl, estas vistas, quiero que tengan el mismo metodo y por lo tanto habia pensado en que ambas implementaran la misma interfaz, mi idea es que sea cual sea tenga instanciada pueda llamar al metodo y que esta me devuelva lo que tiene almacenada. Ahora mismo no se como hacerlo ya que son clases distintas, por eso queria utilizar el polimorfismo. Edito el post inicial mostrando un ejemplo

Comment: @Edulon a ver si te entiendo. La cuestión cual es? Quieres tener un método que reciba una clase que implemente `interfaz` y poder llamar al método? Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo llamarías al método, y si ya tienes un ejemplo, donde estas teniendo problemas?

Comment: @Edulon mira mi respuesta editada, a ver si te ayuda o tienes alguna otra duda

Comment: edito el principal porque veo que no me he explicado bien

Comment: Todo entendido, me había liado y la clase que estaba instanciando no implementaba la interfaz. Aclarado

Answer (score 2):

No sé si entiendo bien tu pregunta, creo que tu problema es que no tienes la firma del método en la interfaz.

Un ejemplo:

Definimos el método en la interfaz, de este modo todas las clases que implementen la interfaz deben tener dicho método:

```
interface InterfazComun
{
    int GetTotal();
}
```

Definimos las clases A y B, ambas heredan de la interfaz. La ClaseA tiene un método adicional, que es propio de la clase, no de la interfaz, por lo tanto la ClaseB no está obligado a implementarlo.

```
 public class ClaseA: InterfazComun
    {
        public char letra;
        public ClaseA()
        {
            letra = 'A';
        }
        public int GetTotal()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public string GetNombre()
        {
            return "Este es el metodo A";
        }
    }

public class ClaseB: InterfazComun
    {
        public char letra;
        public ClaseB()
        {
            letra = 'B';
        }
        public int GetTotal()
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Y un programa de consola que muestra distintas maneras de acceder al método GetTotal():

```
class Program
    {
        public static string DevolverResultadoLetra(InterfazComun interfazComun)
        {
            return "Este es el resultado de la clase pasada como parámetro: " + interfazComun.GetTotal().ToString();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClaseA claseA = new ClaseA();
            ClaseB claseB = new ClaseB();

            Console.WriteLine("Este es el resultado de la clase A "+claseA.GetTotal().ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Este es el resultado de la clase B " + claseB.GetTotal().ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(DevolverResultadoLetra(claseA));
            Console.WriteLine(DevolverResultadoLetra(claseB));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
```

Espero que este ejemplo te ayude. Si no te refieres a esto, favor de especificar un poco mas tu problema.